# How do I change the cursor in Wine?

Tags: wine, cursor

My Current Cursor in Wine is Human(Ubuntu), and I want to change it to Adwaita, so how to do that? it seems crazy when I see the cursor changes when I switch to wine. Sorry I'm Newbie in this Asking Forum.

- Wine   : 1.4.1
- Gnome  : 3.10
- Ubuntu : 13.10 Saucy Salamander [final]

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme 'Adwaita'
```

That should do it. Remember that if you don't have the cursor installed it will do nothing. You can check using:

```
ls /usr/share/icons/Adwaita | grep cursor
```

Wine doesn't use a different cursor than the one is set.